# How to force Emacs not to display buffer in a specific window?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, advising-functions

My windows configuration looks like this:

```
          +----------+-----------+
      |          |           |
      |          |           |
      |          |           |
      |          |           |
      |          |           |
      |          +-----------+
      |          |           |
      +----------+-----------+
```

And I use the lower right window for special displays (like help, completion etc.), but emacs insists on using that window when I call commands (`find-file-other-window`, etc.) that use `display-buffer`, and resize that window as well. It's annoying... Is there a way that I can force emacs NOT to use that windows? I was thinking of advising `display-buffer`, but it's a function in c. Any thoughts on this?

*EDIT:*

Based heavily on Trey's answer, this is what works for me so far:

```
(setq special-display-function 'my-display-buffer)
(setq special-display-regexps '(".*"))

(defun display-special-buffer (buf)
  "put the special buffers in the right spot (bottom rigt)"
    (let ((target-window (window-at (- (frame-width) 4) (- (frame-height) 4)))
          (pop-up-windows t))
      (set-window-buffer target-window buf)
      target-window))

(defun my-display-buffer (buf)
  "put all buffers in a window other than the one in the bottom right"
  (message (buffer-name  buf))
  (if (member (buffer-name buf) special-display-buffer-names)
      (display-special-buffer buf)
      (progn
        (let ((pop-up-windows t)
              (windows (delete (window-at (- (frame-width) 4) (- (frame-height) 4))
                         (delete (minibuffer-window) (window-list)))))
          (message (buffer-name (window-buffer (car windows))))
          (set-window-buffer (car (cdr windows)) buf)
          (car (cdr windows))))))
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, someone already asked the [same question for completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900372/in-emacs-how-do-i-change-the-minibuffer-completion-list-window).  And I wrote up an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900372/in-emacs-how-do-i-change-the-minibuffer-completion-list-window/900440#900440) that seemed to work pretty well.

It looks like you could use that same solution, except instead of adding to `special-display-buffer-names`, you can use the variable `special-display-regexps`.  So something along the lines of:

```
(add-to-list 'special-display-regexps '(".*" my-display-buffers))

(defun my-display-buffers (buf)
  "put all buffers in a window other than the one in the bottom right"
  (let ((windows (delete (window-at (- (frame-width) 2) (- (frame-height) 4))
                         (delete (minibuffer-window) (window-list))))
    (if (<= 2 (length windows))
        (progn 
          (select-window (cadr windows))
          (split-window-vertically)))
    (let ((pop-up-windows t))
      (set-window-buffer (car windows) buf)
      (car windows)))))
```

Obviously you'll have to modify the regexp to not match the `*Help*` and other buffers that you actually want in the lower right window.

Regarding advising `display-buffer`, that would work.  You can advise functions written in c, advice works in pretty much every case you'd want except when functions are *called* from c, or advising macros (which doesn't work b/c the macros are generally already expanded everywhere they're used).

Comment: I saw the other question and indeed used your solution; but my question is not the same. I'm asking not on forcing emacs to use a window but on emacs to NOT use a specific window.

Comment: Right, I don't think Emacs has the ability to exclude windows, so you'll have to use a modified version to exclude the bottom-right window from the window list.  I notice I forgot to do that in my cut/paste hurry, lemme update that.

Comment: When you do (car windows), it actually returns the current windows. But (car (cdr windows)) will work perfectly. Also (- (frame-height) 2) sometimes find the mini-buffer instead (since it sometimes expands to 2 lines), so I use 4 instead of 2.

Comment: I ask quite the same question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941398/can-we-make-an-emacs-buffer-to-be-static-pinned/4941951#4941951) This is the solution. Thanks!

Comment: if: `let' bindings can have only one value-form: if, (<= 2 (length windows)), (progn (select-window (cadr windows)) (split-window-vertically))

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this could work:

```
(defun display-buffer-avoiding-lr-corner (buffer &optional not-this-window)
  (save-selected-window
    (when (buffer-file-name buffer)
      (select-window (window-at (- (frame-width) 1)
                                (- (frame-height) 2))))
    (let ((display-buffer-function nil))
      (display-buffer buffer not-this-window))))

(setq display-buffer-function 'display-buffer-avoiding-lr-corner)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I was thinking of advising display-buffer, but it's a function in c.

```
"display-buffer is an interactive Lisp function in `window.el'."
```

Also, you can advise C functions anyway.

Comment: My emacs says "display-buffer is an interactive built-in function in `C source code'." Version differences, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will make sense for you to make this lower right window dedicated by `set-window-dedicated-p`. Then this window will be ignored in operations like `find-file-other-window` as you want.