# How to make Emacs always open .c files in the left windows while .h in the right?

Tags: emacs, cscope

I always open three windows when writing C code like this:

```
       |
       |  2 
1      |_____
       |
       |  3
       |
```

Window 1 is used for code writing, window 2 is used for cscope, and window 3 is used for header file quick reference.

When I press  in cscope window to show source, I want Emacs to display .c files always in window 1 while .h files in window 3, is there any possible solution?

Many thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002091/how-to-force-emacs-not-to-display-buffer-in-a-specific-window/1002172#1002172) to a similar question.  The key is to use the variable: [`special-display-regexps`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Choosing-Window.html).  It's nearly a drop-in solution, only you choose the window based on the extension (as opposed to **not** choosing a window).