# Can we make an Emacs buffer to be static/pinned?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use an Org file to keep track of my activities, because it's often that I am loosing track of what actually I am aiming to do :)

Now, I would like to reserved a top buffer window with only 5 lines tall and show the narrowed todo from that org file. All other window/buffer activites will not touch that static/pinned buffer.

Is there a way to achieve that result???

Thanks!

EDITED : Can we make that certain buffer to have different background Color? I pressume it's not, because all we have is set-background-color... I hope I am wrong..

Comment: This isn't really specific to Org-mode, so I edited the title.  I'm always interested others' buffer management tricks, as I find the default behavior pretty unsat.

Comment: indeed. that's true! I also add about differentiating colour for that buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you clock in to the Org TODO item, that task will be displayed in the modeline of the current buffer; you might also find that helpful as a reminder of what you're working on.

Comment: That is so nice!. Thanks. I just understand how to use Clock in and Clock out of task. Yes, no top pinned buffer needed.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe setting the variable `special-display-buffer-names` will set you in the right direction.

```
(setq special-display-buffer-names 
      '(("magic buffer"  (width . 70)
              (height . 7)
              (background-color . "green"))
       ))
```

to test certainly made a buffer called "magic buffer" turn up in a small and very very green frame. (For real-life use, of course do go through the customize mechanism by all means.)

ETA: And then, there's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002091/how-to-force-emacs-not-to-display-buffer-in-a-specific-window) which might apply here.

Comment: that' nice! I should give that a try

Answer (score 1):

The original part of the question is a duplicate. See [How do I make this Emacs frame keep its buffer and not get resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151620/how-do-i-make-this-emacs-frame-keep-its-buffer-and-not-get-resized) (which is slightly enhanced over the earlier [Pin Emacs buffers to windows (for cscope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765/pin-emacs-buffers-to-windows-for-cscope)), and the `set-window-dedicated-p` function.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use org-todo-list to show TODO items and org-agenda will show you useful choices such as "M" that filters your TODO items by keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem for a while.  The best solution I came up with was creating a small Emacs frame (size: 80x13) for my Org-mode agenda and placing it in an always-visible portion of my screen.  (Use "C-x 5 2" to create a new frame.)