# How do I make this Emacs frame keep its buffer and not get resized?

Tags: emacs

My Emacs frame looks like this:

```
+---------------------------+
|             |             |
|             |             |
|             |      B      |
|      A      |             |
|             |             |
|             |             |
|             |-------------|
|             |      C      |
+---------------------------+
```

`C` is usually a terminal with some kind of long-running process, like a web server or daemon. Unfortunately, all sorts of things like to switch the buffer in that window and occasionally it gets resized. How can I lock the buffer and height of window `C`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't want to be annoyed by window stealing and resizing, put the following lines in your .emacs for a definitive solution that works **even with libraries like gud that tries to open a new frame when they can't steal your windows** :

(see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812192/emacs-preventing-gud-pdb-from-controlling-windows/5175715#5175715) for info on the following `advice`)

```
(defadvice pop-to-buffer (before cancel-other-window first)
  (ad-set-arg 1 nil))

(ad-activate 'pop-to-buffer)

;; Toggle window dedication
(defun toggle-window-dedicated ()
  "Toggle whether the current active window is dedicated or not"
  (interactive)
  (message
   (if (let (window (get-buffer-window (current-buffer)))
         (set-window-dedicated-p window 
                                 (not (window-dedicated-p window))))
       "Window '%s' is dedicated"
     "Window '%s' is normal")
   (current-buffer)))

;; Press [pause] key in each window you want to "freeze"
(global-set-key [pause] 'toggle-window-dedicated)
```

and customize `pop-up-windows` variable to `nil`.

you could also use [StickyWindows](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/StickyWindows) instead of window-dedicated feature.

Comment: I've had the best luck with function. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the arguments to `pop-to-buffer` have changed in Emacs 24, and that advice causes some havoc.

Comment: For those still having trouble stopping emacs from splitting or resizing a buffer http://superuser.com/a/632050 might be helpful.

Answer (score 12):

One possibility is to *dedicate* the window to its buffer, using `set-window-dedicated-p`.  This will not prevent the window from being resized manually, only protect it from being clobbered by `display-buffer`.  For example,

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (interactive)
        (set-window-dedicated-p (selected-window) 1)))
```

Replace `shell-mode-hook` as necessary.

Comment: using a 't' instead of '1' is even stronger. as in: (set-window-dedicated-p (selected-window) t)  ...refer to: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html

Answer (score 2):

This one also works fine (for emacs 24) https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2007-05/msg00975.html

```
(define-minor-mode sticky-buffer-mode
  "Make the current window always display this buffer."
  nil " sticky" nil
  (set-window-dedicated-p (selected-window) sticky-buffer-mode))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [winner-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Convenience.html#Window-Convenience) to be able to undo the changes to be the window sizes.

You could also [explicitly save and restore the window configuration in registers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/RegConfig.html#RegConfig).