# How do I lock a buffer to a window in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to lock a buffer to a specific emacs window so that when other buffers pop-up they never pop-up in that window or resize it?

Comment: My first thought would be to look at the documentation for `set-window-dedicated-p window flag`.

Comment: I maybe interested in knowing how to do that. Because I plan to try out stumpWM soon or late. And I was foresseing the possibility to use Emacs with one window for each buffer.

Comment: You can find a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151620/how-do-i-make-this-emacs-frame-keep-its-buffer-and-not-get-resized