# in emacs how to control which windows to show compile result?

Tags: emacs, erlang

I have used emacs for erlang programming. According to `http://emacswiki.org/emacs/CompileCommand`, I have configure c-c c for recompile.
In the emacs frame, 6 windows are open, top 3 are for erlang source code reading and writing. 
In the below windows, one is supposed for the compie window.
But when different windows is active and recompile, the *compile* window will switch randomly. How to fix it in one perticular window?

Comment: This is very much the same problem as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002091/how-to-force-emacs-not-to-display-buffer-in-a-specific-window

Comment: I think it's more the inverse of that question -- we don't want to *avoid* a specific window; we want to avoid *all* windows other than a specific one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you start reading at <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `display-buffer` <kbd>RET</kbd> (or in the manual at <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(elisp) Choosing Window")` <kbd>RET</kbd>), you'll find a bunch of ways in which you can modify the behaviour.

It can get a little complex, but something like this might be all you need in your recompile function:

```el
(let ((display-buffer-overriding-action
       '(display-buffer-reuse-window)))
  (compile))
```

I always use dedicated windows when I want to keep things in the one place, so you might also find that useful to look into:

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(elisp) Dedicated Windows")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

I use the `toggle-window-dedicated` function from [Pin Emacs buffers to windows (for cscope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765/pin-emacs-buffers-to-windows-for-cscope/65992#65992) (see also [How do I make this Emacs frame keep its buffer and not get resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151620/how-do-i-make-this-emacs-frame-keep-its-buffer-and-not-get-resized/5182111))